# C++ / GCC - file-scope objects' constructors aren't being called

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor, initialization

I'm beginning to develop for a Renesas RZ/A1L microcontroller. Renesas provide an IDE (e2 Studio - a modified version of Eclipse), set up to compile C / C++ with GCC. Everything works fine, but...

If I declare an object in file-scope (outside of any function), its constructor is never called. For instance:

```
class NewClass {
public:
    int i;
    NewClass() {
        i = 4;
    }
};


NewClass newInstance;

int main(void)
{
    // My program...
}
```

I can tell that the constructor isn't being called because, using the in-circuit debugging setup supplied by Renesas, I can see that i is never set to 4 (even when I place further references to newInstance and i; I have optimisation switched off too). Sorry I can't do a simple cout of i's value - the code is being run in a microcontroller and I haven't worked out how to do that just yet.

If I instead place the `NewClass newInstance;` line inside of main(), then the problem goes away.

A further consequence of the problem is that, for inheriting classes, calling a virtual function on one (via a pointer of base-class type) causes a crash - I suspect due to the constructor having not executed and hence not written to memory some indicator of what class the object was.

By what mechanism would such a constructor normally be called? I did some Googling - would it be the ".ctors" list? (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Initialization.html)

Renesas's "template" C++ project does actually include code to call all of the ctors; however, from looking at my generated .map file for the project, I can see that no ctors are actually present. Does that narrow down the problem - is the GCC compiler not spitting them out when it should be?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: BTW, it is not a file scope variable but a global one. it should require the use of `static` or unnamed namespace to be file scope variable.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting the draft C++11 standard, N3337, we find that:

> [basic.start.main]/1 A program shall contain a global function called
>   `main`, which is the designated start of the program. It is
>   implementation-defined whether a program in a freestanding environment
>   is required to define a `main` function. [ *Note:* In a freestanding
>   environment, start-up and termination is implementation-defined;
>   start-up contains the execution of constructors for objects of
>   namespace scope with static storage duration; termination contains the
>   execution of destructors for objects with static storage duration. —
>   *end note* ]

As you can see, it's implementation-defined in a free-standing environment. Therefore assuming you have a 32-bit x86 GCC toolchain...

---

It sounds like you're in a freestanding environment. If so, if you want to use global constructors, there is some boilerplate you need to implement. The initialization page you linked mentions a linker line, something that would look like this:

```
i686-elf-ld crt0.o crti.o crtbegin.o foo.o bar.o crtend.o crtn.o
```

Assuming `foo.o` and `bar.o` are part of your program, it's **required** that your linker line looks like this. Note that the compiler should provide its own `crtbegin.o` and `crtend.o`, so you can find the location of those using `-print-file-name`. In a Makefile, it'd look something like this:

```
CRTBEGIN_OBJ:=$(shell $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -print-file-name=crtbegin.o)
CRTEND_OBJ:=$(shell $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -print-file-name=crtend.o)
```

Now for the actual initialization function. In the same file as your kernel entry point, call `_init` before `kernel_main` (or whatever it's called.) Optionally `_fini` can be called after `kernel_main` but it's unlikely to be necessary. The exact code will depend on the architecture, but here is an example for 32-bit x86:

```
/* x86 crti.s */
.section .init
.global _init
.type _init, @function
_init:
    push %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    /* gcc will nicely put the contents of crtbegin.o's .init section here. */

.section .fini
.global _fini
.type _fini, @function
_fini:
    push %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    /* gcc will nicely put the contents of crtbegin.o's .fini section here. */

/* x86 crtn.s */
.section .init
    /* gcc will nicely put the contents of crtend.o's .init section here. */
    popl %ebp
    ret

.section .fini
    /* gcc will nicely put the contents of crtend.o's .fini section here. */
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

Comment: Could you explain why this is necessary? Isn't it true that the standard requires the constructors of global objects to be called before control enters `main()`?

Comment: @JorenHeit `main()` and `kernel_main()` are two different beasts. The instructions I've provided are GCC and System V ABI specific, which of course the standard doesn't cover.

Comment: @JorenHeit yes, your setup is not following the standard by default and you have to do some mucking around to get it to work properly.

Comment: @JorenHeit I've added a standard quote.

Comment: @user5381557 Thanks for the clarification!